# Custom training in Keras

Tags: keras

I am using a custom function to define a deep neural network with Keras.

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Xavier initialization (a.k.a Glorot initialization)
Xavier = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()

def Dnn(num_uints_per_layer = 3*[16], act_hidden = 3*['tanh'], num_outputs = 1, act_output = None):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    ## Input layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_uints_per_layer[0], 
                                 activation = act_hidden[0], 
                                 input_shape = (1,), 
                                 kernel_initializer = Xavier,
                                 bias_initializer= Xavier))
    ## Hiden layers
    for layer in range(1, len(num_uints_per_layer)):
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_uints_per_layer[layer], 
                               activation = act_hidden[layer], 
                               kernel_initializer = Xavier,
                               bias_initializer= Xavier))
    ## Output layer
    if act_output: 
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_outputs, activation = act_output, 
                                kernel_initializer = Xavier,
                                bias_initializer= Xavier))
    else:
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_outputs,  
                                kernel_initializer = Xavier, 
                                bias_initializer= Xavier))
    return model
```

I define a simple training function and try training

```
import time

# tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
@tf.function
def train(x, y, epochs=10000):
  for e in range(epochs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      prediction = model(x)
      error = tf.square(y-prediction)
      mean_error = tf.reduce_mean(error)
    gradient = tape.gradient(mean_error, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradient, model.trainable_weights)) # Can add tol cond. to exit after certain accuracy level is reached

    if e % 500 == 0:
      print('Epoch {:5d}/{}, Mean squared error: {:.8f}'.format(e, epochs, mean_error))

x = tf.linspace(-2, 2, 201)
x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)

def f(x):
  y = x**2 + 2*x - 5
  return y

y = f(x) #+ tf.random.normal(shape=x.shape[0]) # If we include noise we can illustrate overtraining

print('Using Keras')
## Define DNN model instance
model = Dnn()
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile() #(x)

untrained_model   = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model) # with Keras
# untrained_model = copy(model)

## Train model
start = time.time()
train(x, y, epochs = 2000)
end = time.time()
print('Finished training with Keras in {:.4f} seconds'.format(end-start))
```

However, no training takes place. But if I use an alternative custom class with the following skeleton code

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, units, activation = 'tanh'):
    super().__init__()
    self.dense1 = ...
    ...
    ...
    self.dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

  def call(self, x, training=True):
    ## Pass x through layers

    return tf.squeeze(x, axis=1)
```

everything works as expected. Can someone explain why when I instantiate with `def Dnn(...)` no training takes place?

Output from the two (normally more epochs are necessary but as is clear from the output training stalls when `def Dnn(...)` is used).

```
Using Keras
Epoch     0/2000, Mean squared error: 17.13852501
Epoch   500/2000, Mean squared error: 6.84089518
Epoch  1000/2000, Mean squared error: 6.83755589
Epoch  1500/2000, Mean squared error: 6.83745432
Finished training with Keras in 18.2301 seconds

Using custom dnn class
Epoch     0/2000, Mean squared error: 22.75801659
Epoch   500/2000, Mean squared error: 0.06296246
Epoch  1000/2000, Mean squared error: 0.04824752
Epoch  1500/2000, Mean squared error: 0.03582729
Finished training with custom class in 14.7489 seconds
```

Comment: You need to define "no training takes place", and also include any error messages that you receive.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I've update the question as requested.